# ValueError: Unexpected result of `predict_function` Use `Model.compile(..., run_eagerly=True)`, or `tf.config.run_functions_eagerly(True)` f

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, neural-network

So I have this model which is supposed to predict the Language:

```
# Initialize CountVectorizer with the vocabulary
vectorizer = CountVectorizer(analyzer='char', ngram_range=(3, 3), vocabulary=vocab)

# Fit and transform the training corpus using the vectorizer
train_corpus = train['text']
train_feat_matrix = vectorizer.fit_transform(train_corpus)

# Get the feature names
feature_names = vectorizer.get_feature_names_out()

# Create a DataFrame from the feature matrix with the feature names as column names
train_feat = pd.DataFrame(train_feat_matrix.toarray(), columns=feature_names)
```

```
#Scale feature matrix 
train_min = train_feat.min()
train_max = train_feat.max()
train_feat = (train_feat - train_min)/(train_max-train_min)

#Add target variable 
train_feat['lang'] = list(train['lang'])
```

```
#create feature matrix for validation set
corpus = valid['text']   
X = vectorizer.fit_transform(corpus)

valid_feat = pd.DataFrame(data=X.toarray(),columns=feature_names)
valid_feat = (valid_feat - train_min)/(train_max-train_min)
valid_feat['lang'] = list(valid['lang'])

#create feature matrix for test set
corpus = test['text']   
X = vectorizer.fit_transform(corpus)

test_feat = pd.DataFrame(data=X.toarray(),columns=feature_names)
test_feat = (test_feat - train_min)/(train_max-train_min)
test_feat['lang'] = list(test['lang'])
```

```
langs = ['eng','fra','spa', 'hin', 'ara', 'jpn']

# Create a LabelEncoder object
encoder = LabelEncoder()

# Fit the encoder to the list of languages
encoder.fit_transform(langs)

def encode(y):
    
    y_encoded = encoder.transform(y)
    y_dummy = np_utils.to_categorical(y_encoded)
    
    return y_dummy
```

```
x = train_feat.drop('lang',axis=1)
y = encode(train_feat['lang'])

#Define model
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(500, input_dim=1050, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(500, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(250, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(6, activation='softmax'))
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'], run_eagerly=True)

#Train model
model.fit(x, y, epochs=4, batch_size=None)
```

```
x_test = test_feat.drop('lang', axis=1)
y_test = test_feat['lang']

# Load the model from the saved file
#model = tf.keras.models.load_model('my_model.h5')

#Get predictions on test set
labels = np.argmax(model.predict(x_test), axis=-1)
predictions = encoder.inverse_transform(labels)

#Accuracy on test set
accuracy = accuracy_score(y_test,predictions)
print(accuracy)

#Create confusion matrix
lang = ['eng','fra','spa', 'hin', 'ara', 'jpn']
conf_matrix = confusion_matrix(y_test,predictions)
conf_matrix_df = pd.DataFrame(conf_matrix,columns=lang,index=lang)

#Plot confusion matrix heatmap
plt.figure(figsize=(10, 10), facecolor='w', edgecolor='k')
sns.set(font_scale=1.5)
sns.heatmap(conf_matrix_df,cmap='coolwarm',annot=True,fmt='.5g',cbar=False)
plt.xlabel('Predicted',fontsize=22)
plt.ylabel('Actual',fontsize=22)
```

But when I try to predict, it shows the following error (ValueError: Unexpected result of `predict_function` (Empty batch_outputs). Please use `Model.compile(..., run_eagerly=True)`, or `tf.config.run_functions_eagerly(True)` for more information of where went wrong, or file a issue/bug to `tf.keras`.):

Why am I getting the above error and how can I fix it?